# Kivy+sqlite3+python Register store data to database cause this problem

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, kivy, kivy-language

i try to create login & Signup page from kivy and sqlite3 database. signup values register to database and takes to user page and when user login it verifies from databases and takes to user page.

login works fine but register to sqlite cause bugs:

i create Register.db that have table name Register and fields "username text" and "password int". it registers both while i give username any text & password any int. but when i give both text it also register and take to user page.

then i tried to open database the command "select * from Login" it shows blank input

i create new project for signup 
here is main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
import sqlite3

class SignupPage(Screen):
    def register(self):
        con = sqlite3.connect("Register.db")
        cur = con.cursor()
        if self.ids["signup"].text and self.ids["passw"].text is not None:
            u = self.ids["signup"].text
            p = self.ids["passw"].text
            cur.execute("INSERT INTO Register VALUES(?, ?)",(u, p))
            self.manager.current = "user"
            con.commit()

class UserPage(Screen):
    pass

class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    pass

kv_file = Builder.load_file('login.kv')

class LoginApp(App):
    def builder(self):
        return kv_file

if __name__ == '__main__':
    LoginApp().run()
```

here is login.kv

```
ScreenManagement:
    SignupPage:
    UserPage:

<SignupPage>:
    name: "signup_page"
    BoxLayout:
        TextInput:
            id: signup
        TextInput:
            id: passw
            password: True # hide password
        Button:
            text: "go"
            on_release: root.register()

<UserPage>:
    name: "user"
    Button:
        text: "back"
        on_release: app.root.current = "signup_page"
```

let me know any mistakes i made or suggestion to improve the code.

Well Here is the code for login main.py that works fine i create new database Login.py for it:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
import sqlite3

class LoginPage(Screen):
    def verify(self):
        con = sqlite3.connect("Login.db")
        cur = con.cursor()

        cur.execute("SELECT * FROM Login;")

        user = self.ids["login"].text
        pswd = self.ids["passw"].text

        cur.execute('SELECT * from Login WHERE Username="%s" AND Password="%s"' % (user, pswd))
        if cur.fetchall():
            self.manager.current = "user"

class UserPage(Screen):
    pass

class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    pass

kv_file = Builder.load_file('login.kv')

class LoginApp(App):
    def builder(self):
        return kv_file

if __name__ == '__main__':
    LoginApp().run()
```

login.kv

```
ScreenManagement:
    LoginPage:
    UserPage:

<LoginPage>:
    name: "login_page"
    BoxLayout:
        TextInput:
            id: login
        TextInput:
            id: passw
            password: True # hide password
        Button:
            text: "go"
            on_release: root.verify()

<UserPage>:
    name: "user"
    Button:
        text: "back"
        on_release: app.root.current = "login_page"
```

Comment: Are your *main.py*, *Login.py* and *login.kv* stored in the same folder? Both your Python scripts (*main.py* and *Login.py*) are loading same filename, *login.kv*. But the content for both are different. You might have a typo error here for *login.kv*.

Comment: No both are in different folders i seperate them after signup have issues